# sigmal algebra and measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be two measures on a $\sigma$-algbra $\mathfrak{F}$ on $\Omega$, such that $\mu (A)=\lambda(A)$ for any $A\in \mathfrak C$, where $\mathfrak C\subset\mathfrak{F}$ is a collection having property if $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathfrak C$, then so is $A\cap B$. Assume there is $A_i\in \mathfrak C$, such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\Omega$ and $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ for all $i$.

Prove that $\mu (A)=\lambda(A)$ for any $A\in \sigma(\mathfrak C)$ where $\sigma(\mathfrak C)$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by $\mathfrak C$.

Comment: Since $A\in\sigma(C)$, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Is in the new edit $C=\mathfrak C$?

Comment: Yes. I will care more about edition next time.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal C=\{A\in \sigma(C)\ ,\ \mu(A)=\lambda(A)\}$, your question is equivalent to show that $\mathcal C=\sigma(C)$. 
easily $\mathcal C\subset \sigma(C)$. 
Now show that $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma-$algebra and it contain $C$ hence it contain $\sigma(C)$..

Comment: Might replace `\mathcal C`by nearly anything with no `C` in it... :-) +1 in advance.

Comment: I have tried to show $\mathcal C=\{A\in \sigma(C), \mu(A)=\lambda(A)\}$ is a $\sigma-$ algebra. But how to show for A  $\in \mathcal C$, then the complement of $A$ is in $\mathcal C$

Comment: The collection $A_i$ are pairwise disjoints .